# set_cookie not working in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie in codeigniter but its not getting set.

```
// create a cookie array for city if of user


        $cookie = array(
        'name'=>'cityId',
        'value'=>$result['city_id'],
        'expire'=>time()+60,   // change time to longer period

        'path'=>'/',
        'secure'=>TRUE


        );


if(!$this->input->set_cookie($cookie))
        echo 'error setting cookie';  // debug deletee
        die();
```

it is returning false always. But if I try to set cookie using `setcookie()`, it works.

Comment: Did you load the cookie helper?

Comment: can you add the body of that `set_cookie` function?

Comment: set_cookie is a library function of Code Igniter. Yes I loaded cookie helper.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your cookie's `secure` parameter to `TRUE`. Are you using a **https** connection? If you're connecting via plain **http**, the `secure` parameter should be set to `false`.

**UPDATE**

Have you checked if the cookie is actually set?

set_cookie in CI will never return true or false so testing

```
if(!$this->input->set_cookie($cookie))
```

is always false.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already considered that point and even tried it with false. But still its not working.